# Is it possible to put my own class into a 3rd party package?

Tags: java, package

Let's say that in my own project I use a 3rd party package named `com.3rdparty.foo`, and in that package there's a class with a package-private field:

```
package com.3rdparty.foo;

public class Bar {
    public void someMethod () { ... }

    int ppField;
}
```

Now I realize that the package-private fields aren't supposed to be accessed outside of that package. But, out of curiosity, is it technically possible to write my own class and attribute it to that 3rd party package, for example, to circumvent the package-private field protection:

```
// MyOwnClass.java

package com.3rdparty.foo;
import com.3rdparty.foo.Bar;

public class MyOwnClass {
    public int hackPPField (Bar b) { return b.ppField; }
}
```

I expect this to be technically impossible. But, if it's indeed so, then I would like to know the exact mechanism of package sealing which prevents you from arbitrarily extending the 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, perfectly possible in the general case. Your class and other classes in the package have to be loaded by the same classloader, if I'm not mistaken, and you can't put classes in certain packages (`java.lang`, for example; in fact, I think it's all the `java.` packages), but in the general case nothing distinguishes your class from other classes in that `com.3rdparty.foo`.